# Не создается девайс DirectX

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx

Учу DirectX и столкнулся с проблемой. Не создается девайс в функции InitDevice().
Привожу код:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <d3d11_2.h>
#include <d3d11_3.h>
#include <d3d11_4.h>

#define ERROR_WINDOW MessageBox(NULL, L"Ошибка: Не создалось окно!", L"Ошибка", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK)
#define ERROR_DEVICE MessageBox(NULL, L"Ошибка: Не создался девайс!", L"Ошибка", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK)

HINSTANCE application = NULL;
HWND window = NULL;
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverType = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureType = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1;
ID3D11Device* Device = NULL;    // Создает ресуры
ID3D11DeviceContext* Context = NULL;  // Вывод ресурсов
IDXGISwapChain* SwapChain = NULL;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* RenderTargetView = NULL;

typedef TCHAR string;

string Class[] = L"Class";
string Title[] = L"Windows API + DirectX";
MSG msg;
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HRESULT InitWindow(HINSTANCE application, HWND window, int mode);
HRESULT InitDevice();
void Render();
void CleanupDevice();

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE app, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdShow, int mode)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrev);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdShow);

    if (FAILED(InitWindow(app, window, mode)))
    {
        ERROR_WINDOW;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (FAILED(InitDevice()))
    {
        ERROR_DEVICE;
        CleanupDevice();
        return NULL;
    }

    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if (GetMessage(&msg, window, NULL, NULL))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
            Render();
    }

    CleanupDevice();
    return msg.wParam;
}

HRESULT InitWindow(HINSTANCE application, HWND window, int mode)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);

    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(application, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(application, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(application, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = application;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = Class;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return E_FAIL;

    window = CreateWindow(
        Class,
        Title,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        application,
        NULL
    );

    if (!window)
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow(window, mode);
    UpdateWindow(window);

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT InitDevice()
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(window, &rc);
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;
    UINT createDeviceFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED;

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] = {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE(driverTypes);

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0
    };
    UINT numFeatureLeves = ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 75;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = window;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

// Вот тут и неработает
    for (UINT i = 0; i < numDriverTypes; i++)
    {
    driverType = driverTypes[i];
// Возвращает что-то не то
        hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, driverType, NULL, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels,    numFeatureLeves,
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &SwapChain, &Device, &featureType, &Context);
// По этому это не работает
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            break;
    }
// И происходит это
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    ID3D11Texture2D* BackBuffer = NULL;
    hr = SwapChain->GetBuffer(NULL, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&BackBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = Device->CreateRenderTargetView(BackBuffer, NULL, &RenderTargetView);
    BackBuffer->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    Context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &RenderTargetView, NULL);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = (FLOAT)width;
    vp.Height = (FLOAT)height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    // Подключаем вьюпорт к контексту устройства
    Context->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);

    return S_OK;
}

void CleanupDevice()
{
    if (Context)
        Context->ClearState();
    if (RenderTargetView)
        RenderTargetView->Release();
    if (SwapChain)
        SwapChain->Release();
    if (Context)
        Context->Release();
    if (Device)
        Device->Release();
}

void Render()
{
    float ClearColor[4] = {
        0.0f,
        0.0f,
        1.0f,
        1.0f
    };
    Context->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTargetView, ClearColor);
    SwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(NULL);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Программа просто для открытия окна

Comment: "Возвращает что-то не то" - это что-то стоит узнать и заглянуть на msdn за описанием проблемы.

Comment: приведите код, возвращаемый D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain, по нему можно понять, что у вас происходит

Comment: Я посмотрел через отладчик что возвращает D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain. Переменная hr получает значение 0x887A0001. Я посмотрел в документации что это. Говорится что приложение предоставило неверные данные параметров. Я хз что там не правильно. Есть идеи?

Comment: Вы передаёте в функцию инициализации окна хэндл глобальной переменной, после чего глобальная переменная перекрывается переданным параметром, в итоге у вас в переменной глобальной лежит NULL.

Comment: BufferCount должно быть 2, как минимум